# What's wrong with this use of EventQueue.invokeLater?

Tags: java, swing, eventqueue

So I was trying to figure out how this snake game works:

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/snake/

When I copied the code into a compiler, I got many errors in this one block of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
         JFrame ex = new Snake();
         ex.setVisible(true);
     });
  }
}
```

Here are the errors: (Line 27 is the EventQueue.invokeLater line)

```
Error: illegal start of expression (Line 27)
Error: illegal start of expression (Line 27)
Error: illegal start of expression (Line 27)
Error: ';' expected (Line 27)
Error: illegal start of type (Line 30)
Error: class, interface, or enum expected (Line 32)
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error messages you get.

Comment: maybe wrong java version? do you use java 8?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have at least Java 8 for using Lambdas (like you do in this example).

For Java 7, you'll need to resort to resort to using `Runnable` instead of Lambda

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      JFrame ex = new Snake();
      ex.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh okay thank you. Is there another way to code this so that it works with java 7? My computer class uses java 7 for some reason

Comment: @LFTY I added a code-example. But since you are following a tutorial, it's very likely that the rest of the code uses Java 8 features as well.

Comment: Hi again, I didn't know how to contact you so this was the only way. I've tried to create a method to make a replay button pop up when the game was over, but I was not able to do it properly. How would I do this?